# React Native Hooks: "Render Error: undefined is not a function" in case of useDimensions() using

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

When I try to use useDimensions() method of the hook library. I can get the error on my Android Emulator, which is Render Error: undefined is not a function.
How Can I fix it?

Note: I am able to use a method from the hook library. e.g. useDeviceOrientation()

[image: Error Screen]

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {
  useDimensions,
  useDeviceOrientation
} from '@react-native-community/hooks';

export default function App() {
  console.log(useDimensions());
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
        width: "100%",
        height: "30%"
      }}></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please type your comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`useDimensions` has been deprecated](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/blob/2ca8dc94326a876ec0f65dd86c36e58022ac7d24/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) in rnc/hooks 3.0.0 (but most examples/tutorials etc will still describe the old method). The missing export presents as an undefined value.

You can just [useWindowDimensions() from react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions) instead.